# BSON Serialization Exception on insert. c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i have this BsonDocument that i'm trying to insert with insertOneAsync :

```
{{
    "starttime": "05.11.2003 17:29:35.189",
    "clk": "0.01",
    "frames": "000001328",
    "typ": "real",
    "MasterRev": "19",
    "WriterVer": "3.0.85",
    "ClientKey": "B4B18CC22F9A4F82FA4D975B53933B5A",
    "Start": "11/05/2003 17:29:35",
    "ID": "File2",
    "InfoCustomEntryA": "AAA0",
    "InfoCustomEntryB": "B1",
    "InfoCustomEntryC": "Just A Standard Entry For The Cold Mill",
    "module_name_0": "RealSignals",
    "module_name_1": "RealSignals5x",
    "module_name_2": "IntegerSignals",
    "module_name_3": "IntegerSignals6x",
    "ibaFilesTest": "12/4/2015 11:46:10 AM",
    "ibaFiles": "6.3.2 Lite (update)",
    "$DATCOOR_status": "processed",
    "$DATCOOR_OutputFiles": "",
    "$DATCOOR_times_tried": "1",
    "$DATCOOR_TasksDone": ""
}
}
```

Getting MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll

How can I debug this?

Had to ignore the meta data when i serialized.  The following works.

```
{{
    "starttime": "05.11.2003 17:29:35.189",
    "clk": "0.01",
    "frames": "000001328",
    "typ": "real",
    "MasterRev": "19",
    "WriterVer": "3.0.85",
    "ClientKey": "B4B18CC22F9A4F82FA4D975B53933B5A",
    "Start": "11/05/2003 17:29:35",
    "ID": "File2",
    "InfoCustomEntryA": "AAA0",
    "InfoCustomEntryB": "B1",
    "InfoCustomEntryC": "Just A Standard Entry For The Cold Mill",
    "module_name_0": "RealSignals",
    "module_name_1": "RealSignals5x",
    "module_name_2": "IntegerSignals",
    "module_name_3": "IntegerSignals6x",
    "ibaFilesTest": "12/4/2015 11:46:10 AM",
    "ibaFiles": "6.3.2 Lite (update)"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete error and stack trace?

Comment: Remove extra curly brackets.

Comment: @Chase, thats my question, how can I get the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @Jason Apologies, my misunderstanding. Are you using a try-catch block around your call to `InsertOneAsync`?

Comment: Aha, thank you @Chase .  Now I'm seeing  Element name '$DATCOOR_status' is not valid'.  Dollar Sign? Hmm, have to google that.

Comment: See my answer, field names can't start with a $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I debug this?

Try placing a try-catch block around your call to `InsertOneAsync`, like so:

```
try
{
    YourMongoCollectionHere.InsertOneAsync(YourBsonDocumentHere);
}
catch (MongoException e)
{
    // examine your exception 'e' here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that caught it.  I just needed to fine tune the serializer settings.  Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extra curly brackets to get valid JSON, however, more importantly Mongo doesn't allow field names that start with  $, see this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3229) ticket.

Comment: BSON has the extra brackets.

Comment: Yes, but they should be square brackets `[ ]` instead

Comment: The outer curly braces are part of the C# object initialiser syntax and are not part of the `BSONDocument` itself, see http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/object-initializers/